# DataDog - Excluding RUM Session Traffic Results From Dashboard

Tags: datadog

I have a dashboard in DataDog that displays Realtime User Monitoring information for an application. The problem is the software that we use internally for monitoring the application is getting reported on in our dashboard. For example, when looking at the browser session data over the past 4 weeks, our monitoring software accounts for 75% of this. **It should only show real user session data.** So, I would like to exclude the monitoring software traffic from our dashboard. What is the right query to us? Here is our query currently:

```
RUM IN Sessions @application.id:324234 env:prod service:web-service @session.type:user
Count: * Group by Browser Name Limit to top 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the `user-agent` header of your automated test, you can use the [`@device.type:bot` query](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/guide/identify-bots-in-the-ui/). Additionally, you should be able to filter on `@session.browser_name`.

The best solution would be to avoid collecting the unnecessary sessions, or reducing how frequently you do so. There are docs on [filtering out bot sessions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/guide/identify-bots-in-the-ui/#filter-out-bot-sessions-on-intake). If you wanted to reduce the number of logs produced by the bot, you could set the `sessionSampleRate` to e.g. 10 to record 10% of bot sessions. With this approach you'll have less data to sort through and a smaller bill.

Comment: Thanks! I did @browser.name:(Chrome OR Edge OR Safari) and it work.